# How to convert e-notation to number in nifi processor

Tags: json, apache-nifi

I have a use case, where i'm getting random e-notation values, Please suggest how to convert them in a number.

Input :

**5.249046E-4**

Expected Output :

**0.0005249046**

We can be done with `replacetext` but our e-notation is not static.
We require 10 digits after the decimal.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `ScriptedTransformRecord` [processor](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-scripting-nar/1.21.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.script.ScriptedTransformRecord/index.html):

- `Record Reader`: `JsonTreeReader`
- `Record Writer`: `JsonRecordSetWriter`
- `Script Language`: `Groovy`
- `Script Body`:

```java
import java.text.DecimalFormat
def df = new DecimalFormat("0.0000000000")

record.setValue("number_formatted", df.format(record.getAsDouble("number")))
record
```

Input (JSON):

```json
{
  "number": 5.249046E-4
}
```

Output (JSON):

```json
{
  "number" : 5.249046E-4,
  "number_formatted" : "0.0005249046"
}
```